# Probability Distributions And Certainty

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

How does certainty effect probability distributions? Here is an example:
I compute the mean and variance of the weight for 10 apples and 1000 oranges.

I am significantly more certain that the mean and variance for the oranges is more accurate than for the apples. Bu how is this measured?

Also lets assume someone was going to purchase X apples and Y oranges. I can compute the mean and variance of the weight of the purchase? But how do I indicate how certain I am of the answer?

Thank You,
Bubba

Comment: Please see our posts about [standard errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22standard+error%22), [confidence intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=confidence+interval+score%3A5), and [sampling distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sampling+distribution).  There are thousands of them, but a few well-chosen ones should get you good answers.